# Express - Command not found

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I am trying to run express on my mac.
I have installed express generator using the following command -

```
sudo npm install express-generator -g
```

I have also tried every alternative command under the sun, no sudo etc. and it tells me it has installed fine. I get this message -

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/express -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
  + express-generator@4.16.0
added 10 packages from 13 contributors in 1.202s
```

But when I try run -

```
express testproj
```

I get this -

```
-bash: express: command not found
```

I've exhausted so many suggested solutions on stack. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/issues/111) on the repo seem to be similar to yours. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the `npm\bin` directory to your `PATH` like this,

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Once done, try executing your `express testproj` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I run that exact command it goes to a new line with ">" symbol on it. So I launched a new terminal window and ran the command but it is still saying command not found unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk Are you using `Mac OS` ?

Comment: yea I am, is that not the expected behaviour? seemed a little strange to me. I copied an pasted it this time and it didn't do that. But still the same results when I run the express command.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk Can you try executing `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` then?

Comment: Still the same result :( . I have even tried reinstalling node but still no luck

Comment: Can you please follow this step by step tutor => https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:~ marc$ express -h
-bash: express: command not found
This is the result again

Answer (score 0):

In my Mac OS, I use the below command, it works for me.

> export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin:$PATH"